# React: How to prefill textboxes with Json data?

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs

I am fetching the data from api.Api that returns json data. Data needs to be prefilled in the textbox and textarea.
The api response is `[{"ProdName":"Test Product","ProdDescr":"Testing"}]`

How to prefill ProdName textbox with value Test Product, ProdDesc Textarea with Testing. Please find webapi code in c#. please let me know whats the best way to get data from sqldatareader in webapi.
reader returns one row with proodid, prodname, proddescr columns.

```
c# WebAPI
[HttpGet("{ProductID}")]

        public JsonResult GetProductInfo(int ProductID)

        {

               var response = GetProductInfo(ProductID);

                return new JsonResult(response);

     }

 

       public string GetProductInfo(int Product_ID)

             {

                    SqlConnection objConnect = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

                    SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand("usp_GetProdInfo", objConnect);

                    objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    objCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Product_ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4));

                    objCommand.Parameters["@Product_ID"].Value = intProduct_ID;

                    string json = string.Empty;

                    List<object> objects = new List<object>();     

                    objConnect.Open();

                           SqlDataReader reader = objCommand.ExecuteReader();      

                                 while (reader.Read())

                                 {

                           IDictionary<string, object> record = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)

                                        {

                                               record.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader[i]);

                                        }

                                        objects.Add(record);

                                 }

                   

                           json =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objects);

                           reader.Close();

                           objConnect.Close();

                           return json;

             }


import React from 'react';

export class Edit_ProdInfo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Prod_ID: '',
      ProdName: '',
      ProdDescr: '',
      ProdInfo: [],
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setProdTextBoxes();
  }

  async setProdTextBoxes() {
    await fetch(REQUEST_URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          Prod_ID: this.props.key_id,

          ProdInfo: data,

          loading: false,
        });

        console.log(this.state.ProdInfo);
      });
  }

  //[{"TemplateName":"CA States","TemplateDescr":""}]

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ ProdName: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <input type='text' ID='ProdName' value={this.state.ProdName} />{' '}
          <textarea
            name='ProdDescr'
            rows='4'
            cols='65'
            value={this.state.ProdDescr}
          ></textarea>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Edit_ProdInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

To prefill the data, You need to call the function inside `componentDidMount`,

```
componentDidMount() {
  setProdTextBoxes()
}
```

Put the `setState` inside the `componentDidMount` or the function inside the `componentDidMount`.

You also need call the function `handleChange` in `onChange` like below,

```
<input type="text" ID="ProdName" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} value={this.state.ProdName}/>
```

So that the state will get updated and the value will replicated in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in below section.
but if you use only single record and have a access of api modification then try to return single record instead of array.
it will avoid indexing [0] in this scenario.

```
async setProdTextBoxes() {
    await fetch(REQUEST_URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
      if(data && data.length>0)
        {
          this.setState({
          Prod_ID: this.props.key_id,
          ProdName:data[0].ProdName,
          ProdDescr:data[0].ProdDescr,
          ProdInfo: data,    
          loading: false,
         });
        }

        console.log(this.state.ProdInfo);
      });
  }
```

Comment: WebAPI is returning single row with prodid, prodname, proddescr data. I have updated the original question with    webapi code in c#. data is coming from sqldatareader. please modify my api/react code if there is any better solution.  In react in case of edit, for particular prod_id, I need to prefill the form controls prodname and proddescr with [{"ProdName":"Test Product","ProdDescr":"Testing"}].

Comment: Just replace **List<object> objects = new List<object>();** line with **var obj=new object();** and **objects.Add(record);** this with **obj=record**